# How to handle CRM outlook offline data from Client

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, outlook-addin

I am working with CRM 2011 outlook client addin. 
I have a button in a CRM page, on click of that button it makes a POST call to some other non CRM service. 
Now I am stuck on a point like how it will behave or how I can handle the call when user will be working on offline mode?

I didn't get any reference from MSDN which can feed my requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove/disable the button from CRM when it is offline by applying a "CrmOfflineAccessStateRule" to your button.
Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334245.aspx

Alternatively you could make a "ping" call to your "non CRM service" to check if it is online or not and then ch